# Is it possible to create a universal iOS framework using bitcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, bitcode

From what I understood, *bitcode* allows to generate binaries with an intermediary binary format. So it is the step before compiling to an ARM or x64 architecture.

It is possible to create "real" `.framework` file for iOS since iOS 8. However, framework files are compiled for only one architecture by default (emulator, iPhone). When one wants to distribute a `.framework` file, it is better to provide a file compatible with the iOS emulator and also deployable to an iPhone. Different examples of scripts can be found to create such a fat file using `lipo`.

However, would it be possible to only distribute a `.framework` compiled as bitcode without having to create a fat file with different architectures?

Unfortunately, even with bitcode enabled for my `.framework`:

- different files are created by default according to the targeted architecture
- even if the "archive" menu seems to be enabled for a framework target, I cannot find the result, even in my Organizer view

Do I misunderstand something in the concept of *bitcode*, or do I miss something?

Answer (score 10):

You need to provide a universal flat framework. Which is created by `lipo`.

- Enable Bitcode, `Targets->Build Setting->Enable Bitcode` to `Yes`
- Add build target to create universal framework

  Create a `Aggregate` target and copy following script to `Build Phrase -> Run Script`:

```
    ######################
    # Options
    ######################

    #verbose
    set -x

    REVEAL_ARCHIVE_IN_FINDER=false

    FRAMEWORK_NAME="${PROJECT_NAME}"

    SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"

    DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"

    UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneuniversal"

    FRAMEWORK="${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"


    ######################
    # Build Frameworks
    ######################
    # Build for simulator
    xcodebuild -target ${PROJECT_NAME} -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} ARCHS="i386 x86_64" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator
    # Build for device
    xcodebuild -scheme ${PROJECT_NAME} -sdk iphoneos -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} ARCHS="armv7 armv7s arm64" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO clean archive CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos

    ######################
    # Create directory for universal
    ######################

    rm -rf "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}"

    mkdir "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}"

    mkdir "${FRAMEWORK}"


    ######################
    # Copy files Framework
    ######################

    cp -r "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/." "${FRAMEWORK}"


    ######################
    # Make an universal binary
    ######################

    lipo "${SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" -create -output "${FRAMEWORK}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" | echo

    # For Swift framework, Swiftmodule needs to be copied in the universal framework
    if [ -d "${SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" ]; then
    cp -f ${SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/* "${FRAMEWORK}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" | echo
    fi

    if [ -d "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" ]; then
    cp -f ${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/* "${FRAMEWORK}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" | echo
    fi

    ######################
    # On Release, copy the result to release directory
    ######################
    OUTPUT_DIR="${PROJECT_DIR}/build/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}-${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneuniversal/"

    rm -rf "$OUTPUT_DIR"
    mkdir -p "$OUTPUT_DIR"

    cp -r "${FRAMEWORK}" "$OUTPUT_DIR"

    if [ ${REVEAL_ARCHIVE_IN_FINDER} = true ]; then
    open "${OUTPUT_DIR}/"
    fi
```

**Note**

- bitcode is only packed on `archive` build for iphoneos sdk
- `otool -l -arch arm64 <yourframework_binary>|grep __LLVM` to check whether bitcode is included, if you don't specify the `arch` parameter, there will be no `__LLVM`, since `otool` just print one host arch(simulator).

Comment: Please read again the question. It is exactly what I would like to avoid (I mentioned `lipo` in my question). I do not understand the purpose of compiling something as bitcode if I need to create a universal binary anyway. And I cannot find the framework file created with the `archive` build.

Comment: bitcode is an intermediate LLVM IR compiled by Xcode, and is arch-dependent, not like the java bytecode, so every slice need its own bitcode section.

Since it's a intermediate code, so apple can use it to optimize to the final machine code in the future without uploading a new version, this is the main purpose

Comment: And the framework created with `archive`  from the script is on  `${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}`

see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW39)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this script! Also 'Skip Install = yes' should be added to avoid  removing a device release from Build/Products/Release-iphoneos

Answer (score 1):

I spend many hours fixing / changing the setup of xfaid's answer to have finaly a universal package with bitcode working with XCode 10.

I couldn't get the "xcodebuild archive" command work, so I used build with the settings described at this link: http://iosre.com/t/enable-bitcode-for-frameworks-in-xcode/12581

I then changed a little the script to:

```
# Fix for bitcode:
unset TOOLCHAINS

######################
# Options
######################

#verbose
#set -x

REVEAL_ARCHIVE_IN_FINDER=true

FRAMEWORK_NAME="${PROJECT_NAME}"

SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"

DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"

UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneuniversal"

FRAMEWORK="${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"


######################
# Build Frameworks
######################
# Build for simulator
xcodebuild -target ${PROJECT_NAME} -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} ARCHS="i386 x86_64" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator
# Build for device
xcodebuild -scheme ${PROJECT_NAME} -sdk iphoneos -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} ARCHS="armv7 armv7s arm64" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO build  ENABLE_BITCODE=YES OTHER_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode"  OBJROOT="${OBJROOT}/DependantBuilds" CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos

######################
# Create directory for universal
######################

rm -rf "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}"

mkdir "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}"

mkdir "${FRAMEWORK}"


######################
# Copy files Framework
######################

cp -r "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/." "${FRAMEWORK}"


######################
# Make an universal binary
######################

lipo "${SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" -create -output "${FRAMEWORK}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" | echo

# For Swift framework, Swiftmodule needs to be copied in the universal framework
if [ -d "${SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" ]; then
cp -f ${SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/* "${FRAMEWORK}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" | echo
fi

if [ -d "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" ]; then
cp -f ${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/* "${FRAMEWORK}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" | echo
fi

######################
# On Release, copy the result to release directory
######################
OUTPUT_DIR="${PROJECT_DIR}/build/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}-${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneuniversal/"

rm -rf "$OUTPUT_DIR"
mkdir -p "$OUTPUT_DIR"

cp -r "${FRAMEWORK}" "$OUTPUT_DIR"

if [ ${REVEAL_ARCHIVE_IN_FINDER} = true ]; then
open "${OUTPUT_DIR}/"
fi
```

Just in case it can helps some of you :)