# Failed to verify bitcode while exporting archive for ad hoc distribution - tried Xcode 8.3.3 & Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, bitcode

Apps containing our framework complains about missing bitcode while exporting archive for Ad-hoc distribution.

I have gone through the documentation provided by Apple in this regard
[Technical Note TN2432](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2432/_index.html). The documentations' listed possible root causes do not resemble our scenario. (We are not using assembly instructions or have malformed info.plist file)

I have gone through following similar questions posted on SO

[Error while exporting with Bitcode enabled (symbol not found for architecture armv7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141793/error-while-exporting-with-bitcode-enabled-symbol-not-found-for-architecture-ar)

[Is it possible to create a universal iOS framework using bitcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35586516/is-it-possible-to-create-a-universal-ios-framework-using-bitcode)

[New warnings in iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848208/new-warnings-in-ios-9)

But the provided solutions do not seem to work.

I have tried adding `BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE` flag in User-Defined build settings. I also tried adding `-fembed-bitcode`-marker & `-fembed-bitcode` in Other C flags in framework target.

I check if bitcode segments are present in my generated framework using the [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35586516/is-it-possible-to-create-a-universal-ios-framework-using-bitcode) command

```
otool -l -arch arm64 <framework_name> | grep __LLVM
```

It shows 2 segments

> segname __LLVM
>
> segname __LLVM

But while exporting the archive, Xcode still complains about absent bitcode.

I tried to upload app on App store to verify if this issue is due to Xcode versions (I tried 8.3.3. and 9.0), but I get following email about build import error from iTunes Store.

> While processing your iOS app, APP_NAME 1.0(4), errors occurred in the app thinning process, and your app couldn’t be thinned. If your app contains bitcode, bitcode processing may have failed. Because of these errors, this build of your app will not be able to be submitted for review or placed on the App Store. For information that may help resolve this issue, see Tech Note 2432.

PS: Disabling bitcode is not an option for us as host app need to support bitcode.

[image: Error while exporting the Archieve]

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The error description took me in the wrong direction to find the solution.

**This error is not related to bitcode.**
It appeared when the framework contained simulator slices (`i386 x86_64`)

Removing them before archiving resolved the issue.

Adding a run script phase to build phases of the target with following code helped in getting rid of the error.

```
APP_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}"

# This script loops through the frameworks embedded in the application and
# removes unused architectures.
find "$APP_PATH" -name '*.framework' -type d | while read -r FRAMEWORK
do
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME=$(defaults read "$FRAMEWORK/Info.plist" CFBundleExecutable)
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH="$FRAMEWORK/$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
echo "Executable is $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

EXTRACTED_ARCHS=()

for ARCH in $ARCHS
do
echo "Extracting $ARCH from $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
lipo -extract "$ARCH" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH"
EXTRACTED_ARCHS+=("$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH")
done

echo "Merging extracted architectures: ${ARCHS}"
lipo -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" -create "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"
rm "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"

echo "Replacing original executable with thinned version"
rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
mv "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

done
```

Credits: http://ikennd.ac/blog/2015/02/stripping-unwanted-architectures-from-dynamic-libraries-in-xcode/

If you don't know how to add a run script phase to your Xcode project, because maybe you're building a project with Cordova or Ionic and you never were taught much about Xcode, here's how you do that:

- Open your project in Xcode.
- Make sure you're looking at your project in the "Project Navigator" by clicking on the left-most icon in the left pane of Xcode (the one that says "show Project Navigator" when you point at it.
- Click on your project at the top of the navigator window, so that it is selected as your target
- At that point, in the middle portion of the Xcode window, you'll see several things appear near the top.  General, Capabilities, Resource Tags, Info, among others.  One of them is Build Phases -- click on it.
- Click the + that's near the top-left of the middle portion of the Xcode Window.  It will say Add New Build Phase if you point at it long enough.
- Select "New Run Script Phase" from the menu that popped up when you clicked on the +
- Click on the arrow next to the Run Script that just appeared.
- Copy and paste the above script into the appropriate area just below the word "Shell".  You shouldn't have to change anything else.
- Build/Archive your project like normal, only now you won't get those annoying "failed to verify bitcode" errors.  :-)

Comment: How you are removing (i386 x86_64), and from where ? And when I click '+' btn to add Runscript, then write your given script as it is provided, It gives the same issue while archiving. Yes I didn't remove i386 x86_64 yet as I don't know how

Comment: Please look into this @Vipin. Though my enableBitcode = NO always, and I don't want to set it to YES

Comment: In Xcode 10, by adding this run script i am getting a crash now which suggests that Alamofire cannot be found:dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A2C3A261-242A-4AF0-A900-CC68DA347B67/myapp.app/myapp
  Reason: image not found

Comment: Hey 
after add that i got error 
"Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code"

Comment: @m.alqadi, Make your you have not accidentally made any syntax error in your script.

Comment: @Vipin you are a god! Thank you so much, this has infuriated me for far too long!

Comment: Thanks, @Vipin it has no relevance with Bitcode process!

Comment: After keeping newly added Run Script at the bottom solved my problem.

Comment: Perfect!! Solved It. Thank You :)

Answer (score 11):

I had to set Enable Bitcode to 'NO' in Build Settings

Comment: It is a solution for sure but not a best one. You disabled bitcode in entire project.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

- Make sure this framework is added under **Copy Frameworks Script** in Build Phases.
- Use BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE instead of BITCODE_GENERATION_CODE

Comment: I actually used BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE in build settings. Edited my question to correct the typo.

I will try to add new "Copy file phase" in build phased. Will add complaining framework in it and let you know about my findings.

Comment: Hey Roy K, as Copy Framework Script Build phase is not visible in xcode build phases, I added Copy file phase with the framework in it. But no luck :(

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. But in my case, I found out after one day of struggle that my system was running out of memory. As soon as I created some space in the system all worked fine.