# How to include dSYM file of an embedded framework to an app archive

Tags: ios, xcode, realm, dsym, xcarchive

My app uses some 3rd party framework. I have a framework itself and dSYM file for it.

When archiving my app, the archive does not contain the dSYM file for this framework. It contains other dSYM files for ther frameworks that're included via Cocoa Pods and built alongside with my app.

I'm using HockeyApp for app distribution, so I'm uploading my app IPA and dSYMs archive to it. But because of lacking of this exact dSYM for this exact framework, I can't see all stack trace in crash reports.

So The question:
How can I kindly ask Xcode to copy dSYM file for the framework? Should I do this manually via script during archiving?

Comment: So, i added extra step In a Jenkins job, that searches for any dSYM in my project and copies it to dSYMs folder in an app archive. Seems it works fine.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you have pre-built frameworks you need to add the dSYM files generated at build time to your Xcode project and add a new "Copy Files Phase" to your target's Build phases in order to end up with them in the Xcode archive.

An example of adding the dSYM files for the Realm framework would look like the screenshot below.

Make sure you select the "Products Directory" destination and the "Copy only when installing" option.

[image: Copy Files Phase]

Now, when archiving your target the dSYMS will appear in the right directory.

Comment: This is kinda OT:  
doing so for our custom framework, compiled with bitcode enabled, causes xcarchive ad hoc distribution to fail with *Failed to verify bitcode in DWARF [...] cannot extract bundle from [...] (arm64)*. We're quite sure this is not an issue of multiple architectures in a single framework, as e.g. happening [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46404236/failed-to-verify-bitcode-while-exporting-archive-for-ad-hoc-distribution-tried).