# How to Include .dsym file of my SDK Framework project into App Project?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, dsym

I have an App that using my Framework binary. When I Archive my App I can able to see .dsym file of my App and pods but not my Frameworks file.

Because of that if there is any crash that happened in my Framework code it's not showing symbolicated crash log...!

My Question:
Is there any way to add Framework .dsym file When I Archive my App?

Note:
If suppose I add my Framework Project to WorkSpace with App Project and then Archive it ..In that case it's showing .dsym files of App and Framework Also.?

Please help Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include dSYM file of an embedded framework to an app archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50947279/how-to-include-dsym-file-of-an-embedded-framework-to-an-app-archive)