# Getting bitcode error while Generating IPA

Tags: ios, ipa, bitcode

I am generating the IPA file to install others device. Please check with the attached image

[image]

Comment: this question's answer might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46404236/failed-to-verify-bitcode-while-exporting-archive-for-ad-hoc-distribution-tried

Comment: @DhavalBhimani I tried from what you suggested a link, But still I'm facing the same issue